# How to get parameter in OnActionExecuting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I modify the default route rule a little bit as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default",                                              // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id= (string)null }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Then I can set url as:

```
/Controller/Action/myParam
/Home/Index/MyParam
```

The default Action Index would be:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
  //....
}
```

I can get the param in action. But I want to get the param in OnActionExecuting. How can I do it?

Answer (score 29):

You should be able to access it with :

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    string id = filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is also exposed via the ActionExecutingContext.ActionParameters property.  The ActionParameters property allows you to see or change the parameters that will actually be passed to the action method.

Comment: @Levi you should post this as answer

Answer (score 1):

It can be accessible from ActionArguments inside OnActionExecuting.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
    string id = context.ActionArguments["id"].ToString();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get controller, action, and all parameters, you can do this

```
    var valuesStr = new StringBuilder();
    if (ctx.RouteData != null && ctx.RouteData.Values != null)
        foreach (var v in ctx.RouteData.Values)
            valuesStr.AppendFormat("/{0}", v.Value);
    _logger.Info("executing {0}", valuesStr.ToString());
    which results in the whole path
```

results with:

```
"/Get/Customer/215840"
```

it should work on multiple parameters just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to retrieve and compare the parameters passed to an action (.net core 3.1).

```
var vals = filterContext.ActionArguments.Values;
var fistobj = vals.FirstOrDefault();
var val = fistobj.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Name, "nameParameter", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).GetValue(fistobj);
if (val == null || val.ToString() != "value parameter")
{
    filterContext.Result = new JsonResult(ExecuteResult.Fail(JanException.Parameter.API00001));
    //base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    return;
}
```

More details for OnActionExecuting and a custom Attribute InitializingActionAttribute

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ControllerActionDescriptor controlActionDescriptor = (ControllerActionDescriptor)filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        var attributes = controlActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.CustomAttributes;
        if (attributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(InitializingActionAttribute)))
        {
            var vals = filterContext.ActionArguments.Values;
            var fistobj = vals.FirstOrDefault();
            var val = fistobj.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Name, "nameParameter", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).GetValue(fistobj);
            if (val == null || val.ToString() != "value parameter")
            {
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult(ExecuteResult.Fail(JanException.Parameter.API00001));
                //base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                return;
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Answer (score -6):

From your filterContext you should be able to get whatever you need.

```
public class MyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       //Do your stuff here
    }
}

[MyAttribute]
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
  //....
}
```